# Why does my rose bush have holes and white spots on the leaves? How can I help it?

Tags: roses

I planted this [Double Knockout](http://www.monrovia.com/plant-catalog/plants/1032/double-knock-out-rose/) rose bush a month ago. It's blooming like crazy but something is eating the leaves and I've noticed white spots on them as well. I have [Sonic Bloom weigalas](http://www.monrovia.com/plant-catalog/plants/3472/sonic-bloom-pink-reblooming-weigela/) on either side and they are doing great. I'm in zone 7a.

Assuming it's bugs, what can I do to prevent them? Maybe add some other small plants around it that deter them?

[image]
[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKybZ.jpg)

Comment: You just have to add a picture or two please!  By your words, you might have powdery mildew, sawfly, one cut worm or two, slugs?  Where is it that you live?  How close are the Weigelas?  You do realize these Weigelas are large shrubs, small trees?  Roses need space and sunlight.  The graft needs to be exposed to air unless you have winters then the graft is covered with mulch until spring.  Zone 7, must be nice.  I am very familiar with the very low numbered zones.  Right now 1B.  Very sad.  Send pictures so that we are able to responsibly answer your question!  Thanks, Brian!

Comment: The picture is in the imgur link at the top of the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be [Sawfly larvae](https://www.google.com/search?q=sawfly%20larvae). I turned over the leaves and found dozens of them one day. I resolved this by purchasing insect spray with Spinosad in it and a simple pressure sprayer. The larvae have gone away and the bush is beginning to recover.